# Как декодировать HTML символы?

Tags: php, символы

Есть много файлов, но в них примерно такое содержание: (`&#x0442;&#x0443`; и т.д.)

Как перекодировать их в нормальный вид? (пробовал html_entity_decode - не помогло)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> пробовал html_entity_decode - не помогло

и что получилось на выходе? возможно, нужно указать нужную кодировку третьим параметром

Comment: на выходе - ничего. Если посмотреть исходный код страницы, будут те же самые символы.

Comment: и как минимум:
string html_entity_decode ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = 'UTF-8' ]] )
По дефолту стоит UTF-8

Comment: с utf-8 должно работать, проверяйте кодировку файлов

Comment: > По дефолту стоит UTF-8

Это если у вас PHP 5.4 и новее.

http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php
"Кодировка для использования. Если не указана, то значением по умолчанию для этого аргумента является ISO-8859-1 в версиях PHP до 5.4.0 и UTF-8 начиная с PHP 5.4.0 и далее."

Так что лучше все же сделать так:
echo html_entity_decode('&#x0442;&#x0443;',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');

Answer (score 2):

```
<? echo html_entity_decode('&#x0442;&#x0443;');       //ту       ?>
```

у меня все работает..

Comment: вы посмотрите исходный код страницы

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич, а что не так с исходным кодом?

Comment: проверил в chrome, firefox, opera -  всё отлично работает, может проблема не с браузером, а с кодировкой файлов, где находятся эти символы (&#x0442;&#x0443; и т.д.)?

Comment: в chrome, исходный код отображает эти же символы

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич, поясните что вы хотите получить!! Если вы хотите заменить все **ФАЙЛЫ** другим содержимым, используйте `file_get_contents` и `file_put_contents`. Если будут проблемы с этим -- пишите, объясню подробно.